# How force Resteasy's (server) cache to reload

Tags: caching, jboss, resteasy

I am using the Resteasy 2.3.6.Final and using the servers side caching feature provided by resteasy cache core.
This works well for GET methods except when the underlying dataset has been changed (presumably through a PUT/POST/DELETE), and I need to retrieve a refreshed version of the dataset.
Is there someway in the POST method where I can specify to resteasy to refresh or invalidate the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the default behaviour of resteasy is to automatically invalidate the cache for a particular URI that has PUT, POST, or DELETE invoked on it. This solved it for me.

Source: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html/Cache_NoCache_CacheControl.html